# Image Thumbnail in product not selected after product import

Tags: magento-1.9, import, product-images, csv, thumbnail

I have problem with product thumbnail. When imported csv file of products I forgotten to add thumbnail column. So because I imported several files of products, I exported all products in one file and in thumbnail column I just copy small_image column links to thumbnail column. But when I import this csv file thumbnail still not selected in products (I did reindex data). What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps for importing products through csv

Step-1 place image in below folder
[magento installation folder]/pub/media/import

Step-2 add image names
in the csv file add names of each image of products in column base_image,small_image,thumbnail_image etc

Step-3 import csv backend

Step-4 add media path
add path to "images file directory" (/pub/media/import)